# Parallel thread execution runs slow on Oreo

Tags: android, multithreading

I developed a game for Android phones some month ago, where I used an algorithm, that took more than 1000ms on some of my older devices (such as Galaxy 5 mini). So I split up the algorithm to run in several threads according to the number of available processor cores, what speeded it up to a reasonable process time (<300ms).

After the last week update to Android 8.0.0 on my htc 10 the execution time increased to 20000 odd ms on that device, for the parallel execution of the algorithm. Reducing the number of threads to one speeds up execution time to less than 1 second. Tests on other devices runnig Android 8 show similar results.

An essential exerpt of my code is this:

```
public class Dispatch {

private final int mTaskCount;
private final int mCores;
private static final String TAG = "asdf";
private Vector<Vertex> mVertexes = new Vector<>();
private Random mRandom;

public Dispatch(){

    mTaskCount = 30000;
    mCores = 1;//Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    mVertexes = new Vector<>();
    mRandom = new Random();
    mRandom.setSeed(42);
    for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++){
        mVertexes.add(new Vertex(mRandom.nextFloat(), mRandom.nextFloat(), mRandom.nextFloat()));
    }
}


public void processTasks(){
    Worker[] threads = new Worker[mCores];
    Log.d(TAG, "Start time    " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    for(int i = 0; i < mCores; i++){
        threads[i] = new Worker();
        threads[i].setPart(mTaskCount / mCores * i, mTaskCount / mCores * (i+1));
        threads[i].start();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < mCores; i++){
        try {
            threads[i].join();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){

        }
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Finished time " + System.currentTimeMillis());
}


private class Worker extends Thread{
    private void setPart(int begin, int end){
        myPartBegin = begin;
        myPartEnd = end;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        for(int i = myPartBegin; i < myPartEnd; i++){
            Vertex v = new Vertex(mRandom.nextFloat(), mRandom.nextFloat(), mRandom.nextFloat());
            for(int j = 0; j < mVertexes.size(); j++){
                float x = mVertexes.get(j).distance(v);
            }
        }
    }

    private int myPartBegin, myPartEnd;
}

private class Vertex {
    public float m_x;
    public float m_y;
    public float m_z;

    Vertex(float x, float y, float z) {
        m_x = x;
        m_y = y;
        m_z = z;
    }

    public float distance(Vertex v) {
        return (float) Math.sqrt((m_x - v.m_x) * (m_x - v.m_x) + (m_y - v.m_y) * (m_y - v.m_y) + (m_z - v.m_z) * (m_z - v.m_z));
    }
}
}
```

What is the reason for this?

Comment: Can you use `ThreadPoolExecuter` instead if creating new Threads.

Comment: `myPartBegin = begin;` You should define `myPartBegin` and `myPartEnd` in the Worker class. Now all threads use the same variable.. My god you did already @#€% who declares that at the end @#€%?

Comment: Why dont you declare `mRandom` local?

Comment: Try with mVertexes local to a thread to.